# How can I suppress column header output for a single SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, output, columnheader, suppression

I'm executing some SQL statements in batch (using the `mysql` command-line binary). I want one of my several SELECT statements to not print the column headers, just the selected records. Is this possible?

Answer (score 327, accepted):

Invoke mysql with the `-N` (the alias for `-N` is `--skip-column-names`) option:

```
mysql -N ...
use testdb;
select * from names;

+------+-------+
|    1 | pete  |
|    2 | john  |
|    3 | mike  |
+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Credit to ErichBSchulz for pointing out the -N alias.

To remove the grid (the vertical and horizontal lines) around the results use `-s` (`--silent`). Columns are separated with a `TAB` character.

```
mysql -s ...
use testdb;
select * from names;

id  name
1   pete
2   john
3   mike
```

To output the data with no headers and no grid just use both `-s` and `-N`.

```
mysql -sN ...
```

Comment: -sN worked well for me to assign the output to a variable in a script: `TABLES=$(mysql -sN -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS`...

Comment: This applies to the entire session, not just to a single SQL statement.  Oracle SQLPlus has `set feedback on` and `set feedback off` which can be used anywhere in a session.  Does MySQL have an equivalent?  Looks like that's what OP was looking for.

Comment: just a brief comment, simplify using **select * from testdb.names;** without explicit 'use'.

Comment: The long option for -s is --silent, for -N --skip-column-names.  -B or --batch also works well instead of -s.

Answer (score 21):

You can fake it like this:

```
-- with column headings 
select column1, column2 from some_table;

-- without column headings
select column1 as '', column2 as '' from some_table;
```

Comment: `Error: Type mismatch: expected type string, but got` error with empty alias

Comment: Looks like that error is coming from MySQL Workbench, not from MySQL.  Anyway you can also use a single blank space instead of an empty string, and that seems to work in MySQL Workbench:
`select column1 as ' ', column2 as ' ' from some_table;`

Comment: this approach leaves an initial blank line that may need to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

A good reason to "... want ... SELECT statements to not print the column headers..." is for documenting output.

Thanks to @tom_warfield I do this:

```sql
select "Relevant details from Stock Entry." as ""\G
select 
      SE.name
    , SED.item_code
    , SED.s_warehouse
    , SED.t_warehouse
    , REPLACE(SED.serial_no,'\n',', ') as serial_no
from
    `tabStock Entry` SE left join `tabStock Entry Detail` SED 
    :
    :
```

My output then looks like this:

```bash
*************************** 1. row ***************************
: Relevant details from Stock Entry.
+--------------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| name               | item_code                     | s_warehouse              | t_warehouse                | serial_no                                                                                                           |
```

Note that `"\G"` instead of `";"` outputs one attribute per line, rather than one row per line.