# if statement in while loop bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to make script that inserts hostname and ip address for certain website in mysql , but before the script inserts results i want to check if they already exist and if it does the script should not insert it.

```
result_check=$(mysql -uroot -p123qwe webs -e "SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUMBER FROM webs WHERE hostname='$hostname' AND ip='$ip'";)
        cat $dir/webs | while read hostname ip; do
    if [[ $result_check -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "INSERT INTO webs (hostname,ip) VALUES ('$hostname','$ip');"
    fi;
    done | mysql -uroot -p123qwe webs;
```

And this somehow does not work , i can think of other way to get the job done(without if) but i want to make it this way.
My webs file looks like that :
somedomain.com 192.168.3.3 ... and etc.

This is the error i get:

*line 23: [[: NUMBER
0: syntax error in expression (error token is "0")*

I have tried many ways to escape this error (changing the brackets from [[ to (( ) but i've had no luck.

Comment: The error is the same , the while loop without the if is working correctly .

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that the output from the first `mysql` begins with `NUMBER`.  Maybe there's a way to suppress column headers?  Ah yes, [the `-N` option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101495/how-can-i-suppress-column-header-output-for-a-single-sql-statement).

Secondly, you appear to require the values that are being read from the file to be present in the query, so you have to rearrange things accordingly.

Additionally, you want to clean up the syntax.

```
while read hostname ip; do
    result_check=$(mysql -N -uroot -p123qwe webs \
        -e "SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUMBER FROM webs WHERE hostname='$hostname' AND ip='$ip'")
    if [[ $result_check -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "INSERT INTO webs (hostname,ip) VALUES ('$hostname','$ip');"
    fi
done <"$dir"/webs | mysql -uroot -p123qwe webs
```

I dislike the temporary variable for the `result_check` but inlining it would hamper readability, so I guess it'll have to stay.

However, a much better approach would be to use native SQL constructs for `INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS` or similar.  See also [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Answer (score -1):

Your code is kosher, so `$result_check` is clearly not a number. Here are some suggestions:

1. Add an `echo if [[ $result_check -eq 0 ]]` before the `if` check to see what's being checked.
2. In Bash it's sometimes helpful to protect against strings being empty. In this case, the protection would be: `if [[ "x$result_check" = x0 ]]`, but you can't do any interesting integer stuff with that check, for example testing equality for "0" and "00" would fail. `if [[ "0$result_check" -eq 0 ]]` should solve that problem, but I haven't tested it. On my system, the `[[` function actually handles the empty string with no problem, so `[[ $undefined_variable -eq 0 ]]` is always true.
3. You can run `type [[` to see what the `[[` function actually is. For me, it's a shell keyword (bash version 3.2).
4. For fun, try the `[` function instead. As long as you use quotes and add a prefix to protect against empty variables, the result should be the same for these simple tests.

Comment: Your second suggestion is only valid for broken and antique shells that should have died a long time ago. Please stop giving such ugly and outdated advices, especially when OP is clearly using Bash!

Comment: I don't know what you think "kosher" means but the code is clearly broken.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf That's good advice. I use the archaic syntax because I occasionally do need to port my code to a weird shell. Unless I'm writing for zsh, in which compatibility be damned!

Comment: This is Bash, not your weird, broken and antique shell. Your advice is just plain irrelevant here.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf You might be amused to know that  FreeBSD, NetBSD, and Android use "weird, broken and antique" shells. (What about Solaris? OpenSolaris?) Also, the last well-known company I worked for used tcsh or all their linux deploys, but that hardly counts, due to being incompatible with all bourne shell conventions, anyway.

Comment: Yes, and Windows uses something else. Come on, be serious, _the question is tagged [tag:bash] and OP clearly uses Bash_. (Sidenote: my FreeBSD uses `tcsh` or `sh` or Bash: one is not a Bourne shell, the other ones are fine and not broken).