# How do you return a value in mysql without a table border?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, shell

## Backstory:

My program SSH's into a remote server and queries wordpress mysql database table for a single value:

```
mysql 
-u boat  
-e "select term_id from boat.wp_terms where name = \"programming\" LIMIT 1;" 
--password='programming' 
--disable-column-names
```

Which returns:

```
+----+
| 15 |
+----+
```

Rather than having to write that extra bit of code parsing out the

```
+----+
|    |
+----+
```

Is there an argument I can just add to my query so it simply returns:

```
15
```

?

Ultimately I will need to set a script $variable to the value returned.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101495/how-can-i-suppress-column-header-output-for-a-single-sql-statement

Comment: @codeforester Ah! I knew this question had to be a duplicate. I just wasn't sure how to word it to find an answer.

Comment: The short answer is `-s`. Thanks!