# Procmail recipe returned column name and result

Tags: mysql, procmail

I use procmail to filter email which involves retrieve result from mysql, but Procmail recipe returned column name which I don't want and result.
   variable result is not declared or used before the line:
   Here is the line in my procmail:

```
{
 result=`mysql -uuser -ppasscode dbname -e "select raw_data from tablex where id='"$msgID"'`
 result=`echo "$result" 
}
```

How to trick it/rewrite it not to return `raw_data` in the result?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Procmail question.  Specifically, for MySQL, the way to get a query result without headers is to use `mysql -N -s` as detailed in the [nominated duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101495/how-can-i-suppress-column-header-output-for-a-single-sql-statement).

In the more general case, you can use arbitrarily complex shell script inside the backticks.  To suppress the first line of something, pipe it through `tail +2`.

```
result=`mysql ... whatever | tail +2`
```

The braces are not doing anything useful in this limited context (though if this is the action part of a recipe which you are not showing us, they are necessary there).  Similarly, `` result=`echo "$result"` `` is not doing anything useful at all, just starting another shell to assign the variable's value back to itself, [clumsily.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)