# How to remove header row while using OFFSET and LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using below query to fetch data from tables.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

but the result seems to have headers with it, how to get rid of those headers.

Thank you

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @jester, want to pull records without headers using OFFSET

Comment: its for partitioning of data first 1000 records in one array (i.e 1 -> 1000) and next 1000 records in another array like (1001 -> 2000).

Comment: @vignesh. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101495/how-can-i-suppress-column-header-output-for-a-single-sql-statement

Comment: Please show us sample data which includes the "header" which you want to remove.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, `SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0` output is like `| EMPLOYEE_ID | first_name | last_name | Primary_email                | secondary_email        | gender | ip_address    | Primary_NO      | Secondary_No    | Pincode | | P00100001   | Donald     | Harrison  | Destinee_Schiller@brandyn.us | gharrison0@booking.com | Male   | 32.69.240.244 | 1-(216)488-8819 | 1-(573)770-6641 | 15      | 34     |` I have copied only few columns the table has 150 columns.

Comment: OK your header labels should NOT be in the table.  Reimport your data and don't use the first line.  I am scared to even ask what the types of each column ended up being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the first row containing the header data and you are good to go

```
delete from TABLE_NAME where id=1;
```

am assuming the first row has the header information