# How to export data to csv in mysql without the header?

Tags: mysql

MySQL has the functionality to export the data to a CSV file with following statement

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    person
INTO OUTFILE 'person.csv' 
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TERMINATED BY ',' 
ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

But by default it will has the column name as the CSV **header**, so how to remove the header in this statement?

I reviewed the mysql reference but seems these is no such info.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it automatically, you'll have to edit the file afterward, or write code in a client language to do it.

Comment: BTW, it's probably not a good idea to do this with `select *`, in case you change the order of columns in the table. Use explicit column names in the select list.

Comment: For a very large csv file, ~1GB, it is really hard to open and edit it.

Comment: Yep, `select *` is just a sample, in real  statement, I added the concrete fields indeed, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: `tail -n +2 file.csv > filewithouthead.csv`

Comment: you can use `mysql --skip-column-names`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After complete the csv file, seems for the huge records, the big csv file has no **header**, so if you want to add the header, following:

> Several users asked about including headers, i.e., column names or variable names, in the "INTO OUTFILE" syntax.
>
> One approach is to use the "--column-names" option in the mysql invocation:
>
> `mysql --column-names -e 'SELECT * FROM mysql.user' > test.dat`
>
> (This creates a tab-delimited file test.dat with column names in the first row followed by the query results.)

Answer (score 1):

2 options are provided in this post : [How can I suppress column header output for a single SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101495/how-can-i-suppress-column-header-output-for-a-single-sql-statement))

## 1 : invoke mysql with -N flag will skip all column headers

## 2 : fake it

```
select column1 as '', column2 as '' from some_table;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    person
INTO OUTFILE 'person.csv' 
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TERMINATED BY ',' 
ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';

change FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' line
with OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
```